# text-align: center is not effecting display: inline-block

Tags: html, css, web

I'm pretty new to this, so please forgive me if I need to be a tad more descriptive. I have a subtitle on my website I want centered under by title. However, I also want to give the subtitle a bottom-border. I want the border to be the equivalent length of the subtitle though, so I figured I'd display: inline-block and text-align: center. Then, apply by bottom border. However, its not working. The subtitle stays aligned to the left. I've attached my HTML and CSS below:

[My HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liIFo.png)

[My CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2WO2.png)

[What my page currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9aBE.png)

Comment: For future reference you should post your code in the question, not links to images. It makes it much easier to copy code snippets to see what went wrong. In your case it was okay because they were short but try not to get into bad habits ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this: [**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/PjARh/)

By applying **padding-bottom** you can achieve this.

**CSS:**

```
h2 {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick way to fix your problem would be to get rid of `display: inline-block;` and the `border-bottom` and add the `text-decoration: underline` property. [Check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tbp69/) to see the result.

Comment: Thank you! I was considering that, but I want the underline to be further down from the text. Thats why I figured I'd use a border and give it a top margin. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @KenFedor Well I don't approve of this method but http://jsfiddle.net/HPLFt/ there's another jsfiddle that does what you want. It involves giving the h2 a width and setting it to be margin: 0 auto (centering it). This is bad because if you change the text or the font size you have to change the width also. Then add padding-bottom to change how far the bar is from the text.

Comment: Okay, I'll play around with it! Thank you so much for giving me an answer this late at night, haha.

Comment: Agreed. @A.K 's answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

just give the `text-decoration:underline;` rather than border-bottom;

**HTML**

```
<h1>tittle</h1>
<h2>subtittle</h2>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
text-align:center;
}

h2 {
text-align:center;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

see the demo:- http://tinkerbin.com/7LQqmXkZ

**UPDATED ANSWER**

You can use the `span`tag under `h2` and give `border-bottom` to `span` tag than give `padding-bottom` so i hope you will get it your desired results....

**HTML**

```
<h1>tittle</h1>
<h2><span>subtittle</span></h2>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
text-align:center;
}

h2 {
text-align:center;
}

h2 span {
border-bottom:1px solid red;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

http://tinkerbin.com/gUQO8U7u

Comment: Thank you as well! Like I was considering that, but I want the underline to be further down from the text. By applying a top margin or something. Is that possible?

Comment: @Ken Fedor: By applying padding you can achieve this, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `text-align: center` to a block containing the `h2` rather than the `h2` itself, since when the element has been turned to an inline block (for the purpose of setting its width to the minimum width required by the content), it’s useless to center its content. (That would only center the text contain within a box of the same width as the text.)

The problem can be reduced to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<hgroup>
<h1>Ken Fedor</h1>
<h2>Designer. Developer. Dreamer.</h2>
</hgroup>
```

The fix here is to add the following to the style sheet:

```
hgroup {
  text-align: center;
}
```

(This is what makes the jsfiddle demo in A.K’s answer work: this code is there, though not mentioned in the answer text. The use of padding is irrelevant to the issue.)